# How do I reset my UV window?

Tags: mesh, uv, 3d-view, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

The object in that window are not showing up whereas it is right in 3D View:

[image]

**Q:** How do I reset my UV window to display the object properties?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What do you mean by *"The objects in that window are not right while in the other viewport are right"*? It's not very clear from the screenshot :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I have modeled a doughnut and a coffee cup but I can find/see (they are not displayed as in the layout window) in the UV window. On the screenshot attached, in the right viewport, there is only some kind of a empty ''shadow'' in the 3D space.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @JachymMichal hello, did you check the file I just uploaded? What was the issue?

Comment: Hello @David :). You need to share the link the *blend-exchange* site generates after upload. Otherwise we can't access your file :)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=knXyXOs4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/knXyXOs4/) @JachymMichal Is that it?

Comment: That was it @Daniel. Answer is up now :).

Comment: Thank you! :) @JachymMichal

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted **✓**. To keep the site nice and tidy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Workspaces.
Simply create a new UV workspace an then it should work.

<kbd>+</kbd> > General > UV Editing

[image]